# Magento 2 - Custom Head PHTML showing in body

Tags: magento2, layout, head, default.xml

I am trying to create dynamic head using phtml on `Magento 2.3.5 p1`.

I am inserting in default.xml the following:

```
<page>
<body>   
...
 <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_head_file" template="Magento_Theme::custom_head.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
...
</body>
</page>
```

The output of `custom_head.phtml` is showing inside the **BODY** and not inside the **HEAD**.

Any ideas on how can this be debugged and corrected? I also tried `refereceBlock` and the result is the same.

Comment: I just try your code and it is correct and phtml connect showing just before </head>

Comment: Please make sure your default.xml is being processed by Magento

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The problem was not in the default.xml, but in the content in the custom_head.phtml.

I had originally

```
echo "testing";
```

Once i changed the content of custom_head.phtml as shown under it works.

```
echo "<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//www.google.com/'>";
```